# how to write proper method?

Tags: ruby, class, methods

```
class Mycompute

  def initialize(str)
    @str=str
  end

  def values
    @@result=@str
  end

  def up
    @@result.upcase
  end

end
```

```
irb(main):012:0> Mycompute.new("Abc").values

=> "Abc"
irb(main):013:0>

irb(main):014:0* Mycompute.new("Abc").up
=> "ABC"
irb(main):015:0> Mycompute.new("Abc").values.up

NoMethodError: undefined method `up' for "Abc":String
  from (irb):15
  from :0
```

How can I  make `Mycompute.new("Abc").values.up` work?

Comment: Voting to close, can't find a question here.

Answer (score 0):

The object returned from `values` need have `up`.

```
class Mycompute

  def initialize(str)
    @str=str
  end

  def values
    @@result=@str

    def @@result.up
      self.upcase
    end

    @@result
  end

  def up
    @@result.upcase
  end

end
```

This works well.

```
Mycompute.new("Abc").values #=> "Abc"
Mycompute.new("Abc").up #=> "ABC"
Mycompute.new("Abc").values.up #=> "ABC"
```